# API redcap and logs

Tags: logging, redcap

I have a problem with importing logs from the redcap API on Stata. We have several visits which are carried out under the same instrument (visit with M1 M2 M3). When I look at the logs directly in redcap it clearly says in the actions "Update Patient_x record (Visit M02)", but when I use the API it only says "Update Patient_x record" , so I cannot determine which visit the variable refers to. How to do in this case to know which visit this corresponds to? Thanks !